# Error thrown on navigator pop: "!_debugLocked': is not true."

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

the problem appears when i call any of the `Flat Button`,  I'm sure that the problem is related with the  `pop()`  i already tried this two things,

> - [Error thrown on navigator pop until : "!_debugLocked': is not true."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true)
> - [Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2216 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027568/another-exception-was-thrown-packageflutter-src-widgets-navigator-dart-fail)

but without luck until now, so i would appreciate any help, thx =)

```
 showPickerDateRange(BuildContext context) {
    Picker ps = new Picker(
        hideHeader: true,
        adapter: new DateTimePickerAdapter(type: PickerDateTimeType.kYM),
        onConfirm: (Picker picker, List value) {
          print((picker.adapter as DateTimePickerAdapter).value);
        });

    Picker pe = new Picker(
        hideHeader: true,
        adapter: new DateTimePickerAdapter(type: PickerDateTimeType.kYM),
        onConfirm: (Picker picker, List value) {
          print((picker.adapter as DateTimePickerAdapter).value);
        });


    List<Widget> actions = [
      FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              });

          },
          child: new Text(PickerLocalizations.of(context).cancelText)),
      FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              ps.onConfirm(ps, ps.selecteds);
              pe.onConfirm(pe, pe.selecteds);
              });
          },
          child: new Text(PickerLocalizations.of(context).confirmText))
    ];

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Select Date Range"),
            actions: actions,
            content: Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Begin:"),
                  ps.makePicker(),
                  Text("End:"),
                  pe.makePicker()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

this is the terminal output

```
I/flutter (28546): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2113 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter (28546): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2113 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter (28546): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:42:39)
E/flutter (28546): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter (28546): #2      NavigatorState.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2113:12)
E/flutter (28546): #3      _HomeState.showPickerDateRange.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:agence_test/home_agence.dart:170:37)
E/flutter (28546): #4      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:316:39)
E/flutter (28546): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
E/flutter (28546): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (28546): #7      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (28546): #8      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (28546): #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter (28546): #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (28546): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:949:23)
E/flutter (28546): #12     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter (28546): #13     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
E/flutter (28546): #14     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
E/flutter (28546): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
E/flutter (28546):
```

flutter doctor result

```
• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?